# SpringSource Tool Suite can't import spring library classes

Tags: spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm just learning Spring and tried out the example Hello World app [here](http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-ide-1.html) on my installed STS.

However, none of the imports are working. I've tried installing various times, without any change. Is there any post-install or post-project creation steps I need to perform, to get this right?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a very old tutorial.  I'd recommend trying a more modern tutorial, like the one here.

http://blog.springsource.org/2012/04/09/create-spring-integration-projects-using-sts/

The tutorial describes how to create  aslightly more complicated project, but it uses the most recent STS and this should be something that works for you.